# Techniques for minifying and optimizing the js code, are they really working?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I'm wondering does any of the following techniques adds any performence:

- !!variable - I see this in jquery and its plugins - cast to bool
- null == variable - this can be usefull if you miss the second equals. But someone in SO claimed this is because of the gzip optimization
- minification and shrinking of the variables - about this I'm interested about IE, can it benefit from the shrinking of the variables

Which are true and which are just useless?

Comment: Minification does not affect performance at all. It is just to save bandwidth.

Comment: @freakish What about the shrinking of the variables? Can this do both?

Comment: Shrinking variables won't give you any performance boost. If you need performance, then you have to refactor your JS code. It won't magically become efficient. Neither IE nor any other browser will benefit from minification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, minification works to build smaller files, if you don't try to do it yourself but use a minifier like the excellent [Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

Regarding execution performances, the gain isn't noticeable, it can even be slightly negative, depending on how it's done. But that's not the goal : the goal is to save bandwidth.

There is no reason to write a minifier yourself unless you feel confident enough that you can do better that what's provided by the proven ones. It's not an easy task.

Now, looking at your first specific tricks (the two first propositions), they're mostly useless for minification.

Note that JS minification is independent of the JS engine, there is no specific IE problems here.

Answer (score 0):

Minifying works. The main goal is to make the resulting JS file smaller so that the page doesn't use that much bandwidth when loading jS resources. Minifiers such as Google's Closure Compiler can go further by performing tasks like dead-code elimination which can shrink the code down even further.

**UPDATE**

Your first two examples don't really apply to minification and the performance-savings are negligible. Google's Closure Compiler will, as I mentioned before, perform dead-code elimination. But what it can also do is perform function and constant inlining, which may provide you some performance benefits, but as far as I know, even the most aggressive optimizations don't do much more than this. That is, I don't know of any minifier that transforms your code into more-performant code. I don't know how much IE would benefit from this, but I would say that since the code really isn't being transformed aggressively into more-performant code, there wouldn't be too much of an effect. Perhaps the shrinking of variables would mean that less memory is taken up in the symbol table inside the browser, but I don't think that is buying you much.

Comment: I know about the bandwidth savings, but they are not a concern for me. Most of the pages are for local network. But the oroblem is that the client is really fat, and sometimes IE is really slow. Can you say anithing about the first and the last point?